# Priority Queue not printing the values pushed into it

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I just started Data Structures and i have stumbled upon Priority queues, I wrote a simple program to print the values that i have pushed in the Queues but it wont print anything.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    priority_queue<int> maxi;
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> mini;

    int m = maxi.size();
    int n = mini.size();


    maxi.push(1);
    maxi.push(3);
    maxi.push(2);
    maxi.push(5);
    maxi.push(0);
    
    cout<<"Max size->"<<maxi.size()<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cout<<maxi.top()<<" ";
        maxi.pop();
    }cout<<endl;

    mini.push(1);
    mini.push(3);
    mini.push(2);
    mini.push(5);
    mini.push(0);

    cout<<"Mini size->"<<mini.size()<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        cout<<mini.top()<<" ";
        mini.pop();
    }cout<<endl;
}
```

I have read so many articles i just dont seem to find any error. Even the Compiler doesnt give any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the size of maxi and mini *before* adding elements to them. Since you're copying the value of the size (explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)), it wouldn't be updated when adding elements to the containers. Therefore your loop is not executed at all.